# How to pass value as array in HTML/Angular

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs

I've a form where m having two controls. One is MovieName and other MovieCast.

On submit, i'm saving the values in DB.
**MovieName** : String
**MovieCast** : Array

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="adduserform" id="formid">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.Movie_Id" name="MovCast" class="form-control"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.Cast" name="MovCast" class="form-control" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="Save()" class="btn btn-primary" />
   </div>
</form>
```

Angular :

```
 $scope.Save = function () 
     {
         var Movie = {
                        _movieId: $scope.user.Movie_Id,
                        _cast: $scope.user.Cast
                      };
         var promisePost = MyService.postNew(Movie); //call to WEBAPI to store
         promisePost.then(function (pl) {
        alert("Movie Saved Successfully.");
     }
```

Problem is as Cast data type is array, value entered is passing as `Null`
1) How to handle array inputs in UI and angular
2)Can i use two or more text boxes?(but looks messy)
3)If gona use single text box how can partition values as array value

Example of Cast entry : Arnold, Tom Cruise....

help me how to handle array inputs????

Comment: If you use one text box then you delimit them using a comma or something. When you're about to post your form you can use JavaScripts `split(',')` to split that string into an array.

Comment: You'll have to implement this yourself as a directive, or use some existing library. http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main for example

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a UX question as well, and would be the perfect opportunity to create a simple custom directive:

## [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YAJyuQ?p=preview)

I used Bootstrap in the demo to apply some nice styling, but you can use your own template and custom styles.  The example below shows just a barebones template without Bootstrap applied.

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('tagInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { tags: '=' },
        template:
          '<input type="text" placeholder="Add an Actor..." ng-model="addval"></input> ' +
          '<button ng-click="add()" type="button">Add</button>' +
          '<div class="tags-list">' +
            '<span ng-repeat="(index, tag) in tags" ng-click="remove(index)">{{tag}}</span>' +
          '</div>',
        link: function ( scope, element ) {
            var inputelem = element.find( 'input' );
            
            // Add an item to the tags array
            scope.add = function() {
                if (scope.addval.length) {
                  scope.tags.push( scope.addval );
                }
                scope.addval = "";
            };
            
            // Remove an item from the tags array
            scope.remove = function ( index ) {
                scope.tags.splice( index, 1 );
            };
            
            // Add actors when ENTER key (keyCode === 13) is pressed
            inputelem.on( 'keypress', function ( event ) {
                if ( event.keyCode === 13 ) {
                    scope.$apply( scope.add );
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The directive is pretty simple.  It defines two methods in the link function: One to add 'tags' to the list and one to remove them.  To make it nicer for the user, I added an event handler that listens for the `ENTER` key being pressed in the input field.  This way the user can either press the `ADD` button or the `ENTER` key to add a new item.

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('ActorCtrl', ['$scope', function ( $scope ) {
    $scope.actors = [];
}]);
```

When you call your save function, you'd just pass in the $scope.actors for your cast.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="ActorCtrl">
  <tag-input tags="actors"></tag-input>
</div>
```

The `tags` attribute allows you to pass in the name of the `$scope` property name for the array in the controller.  This makes the directive a bit more reusable. In the demo, you can see that I also added a `label` attribute so that you can use that value in the template.

To provide a better user experience, I also added some custom styles that change the background-color of the 'tags' and add an 'X' when you hover over them.  Of course, this would be useless for mobile users, so I provided a bit of instruction in the template as well.

There are certainly ways to further improve this and provide even better separation of concerns, but it's a fairly simple implementation that you can adapt to your needs.